# Subdifferential of a convex function and a continuous mapping

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, subgradient

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be convex and $x^*\in int(dom (f))$. If there exists a mapping $g:int(dom(f))\to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying

1. $g(x)\in\partial f(x)$ for any $x\in int(dom(f))$
2. $g$ is continuous at $x^*$

Then $\partial f(x^*) = \{\nabla f(x^*)\}$.

I know that there is a theorem stating that the conclusion is true when [$f$ is convex differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989117/subdifferential-of-a-convex-differentiable-function). I tried to prove "the existence of $g$ implies $f$ is differentiable", but I am confused and cannot make reasonable inductions.

Please help me with the idea of this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you prove it in case $n = 1$?